# adding product quantity in the mysql field from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP&MYsql application I have a stock table with fields:

```
stock_id,
stock_name,
stock_code,
stock_desc,
quantity,
date of purchase
```

All the data for this table are entered by admin from the `stock register` screen in front end.

```
1  HI0001   Pen      This is a item for writing 2013-12-18          15      
2  SO0002   Duster   This item is               2013-12-18          12       
3  HO0003   Board    This is for demonstration  2013-12-17          15
```

Now My question is for example if admin again enters a new stock with `stock_name:pen`  and `quantity:10` how can I save the `quantity(10 + 15)` i.e 25 in `quantity` field instead of creating a new row in the table?

I only have the above fields in my table and the `stock_code` is a field that will increment one each time when a record is added. So can't do much with the `stock_code`.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Comment: if you tried any php code then please post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query to see if you already have a record for that stock_name and then you can run the appropriate query.

```
SELECT COUNT(stock_name) AS CNT FROM stock table WHERE stock_name = Pen;

IF CNT > 0 THEN
   UPDATE stock table SET quantity = quantity + new qty WHERE stock_name = pen
ELSE
   INSERT INTO ....
```

hope this can help you ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try to work it out the way you suggested